# How do I solve the homogeneous differential equation.$ z '' - 4z '+ 13z = 0,$ $z (0) = 7, z' (0) = 42.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is an example that my teacher has already solve, but I dont understand how, so I wanna know if its just yhe way he did that confused me.

The answer is $z=e^{2x}(7 \cos(3x)+ 28/3 \sin (3x)).$

thanks

Comment: The standard method for solving these equations is to assume there's a solution of the form $z = e^rt,$ and then after plugging the derivatives into the equation you get a quadratic in terms of $r.$ Are you familiar with this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a second order homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients. This means you *try* a solution $z(t) = {\rm e}^{\lambda t}$, with $\lambda \in \Bbb C$. Real and imaginary parts of a complex solution to such a real equation are also real solutions. Plugging this $z(t)$ leads to the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-4\lambda+13=0$. Complex solutions to real polynomial equations come in conjugate pairs, so this means we only care about $\lambda = 2+3{\rm i}$. Hence $$z_{\bf c}(t) = {\rm e}^{(2+3{\rm i})t} = {\rm e}^{2t}(\cos(3t)+{\rm i}\sin(3t))$$is a complex solution. This means that $$z_1(t) = {\rm Re}(z_{\bf c}(t)) = {\rm e}^{2t}\cos(3t)\quad\mbox{and}\quad z_2(t) = {\rm Im}(z_{\bf c}(t)) = {\rm e}^{2t}\sin(3t)$$ are real solutions. Two linearly independent solutions will span the space of all solutions to a second order homogeneous ODE, so the general solution looks like $$z(t)=Az_1(t)+Bz_2(t) = A{\rm e}^{2t}\cos(3t)+B{\rm e}^{2t}\sin(3t),$$where $A$ and $B$ are determined in each case by the initial conditions given --- in this case, $z(0)=7$ and $z'(0) = 42$.